# How to connect json file with c#

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I have Json file connected with database: http://222.255.29.210:9000/pk/api/index.php/fbids

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4dSP.png]

In code boder red: If I set "des = true" in database then tool run, if I set "des = false" then Winform c# close. Use Json data

Comment: What are you meaning? I understand nothing what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your data on JSON come from database right ?

So, use [Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to determine your program in c# 
to read that json object and check is "des = true" or not.